# clearing information from registry

Tags: windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows registry and system cleaner applications ?](https://superuser.com/questions/6668/windows-registry-and-system-cleaner-applications)

I have uninstalled a software,but more over i want to clear all registry's information about that specific software;
Is it possible?